# High E string first 2 frets produce buzz on electric guitar

Tags: electric-guitar

The first two frets produce a buzzing noise on the high E string. The open high E sounds fine. Also, the second fret sounds similar to the third fret. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the third fretwire is slightly high. Tapping it gently may re-seat it, or possibly filing it down, only under the 1st string part. Beware that doing that may move the problem up to the next fret, as the third fret may go too low.

Comment: if the fret crown is fully seated against the fingerboard, tapping it down won't help.  Look at the fret edge at the fingerboard for a thin crack or line if the fret isn't seated all the way.  If seated then the fret is higher than the others and requires leveling.  A fret level job by a trained technician is the best option. If doing it yourself don't try to level just the one fret; the frets around it should be leveled down to match at the same time.  You can find high and low frets by marking the tops of the frets with a marker and rubbing a flat emery board/ nail sander across them

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to sanding the fret is to adjust the string height - with an electric guitar, you should be able to do this at the bridge.

Generally, raising the string would be more of an option if you get buzz on more than a couple of frets.

Answer (score 0):

Your third fret is a little bit high. If you change any part of your guitar it will effects some other parts. So try to do these steps:

1) The best choice is to make 3rd fret lower , it has to be done very carefully , you may effect other bars (if you do it wrong you may have this buzzing on 4th and 5th and etc.)

2) Your second choice is to change the entire string's height with adjusting "bridge". It may effect your playing so don't change it a lot.

3) And if still buzzing! finally try to do something with "nut". It's not recommended and it has to be your last choice. Because it will change other strings's heights.

Comment: adjusting the nut won't help with fret buzz. No matter how high the nut action is set, as soon as you press the string to a fret, the action is now from that fret to the bridge, and high frets in the path will buzz. Raising the action at the bridge is the easiest fix, but can put your action uncomfortably high.

Comment: I think it's depend on which Instrument you using. You have 2 options, lower the fret or higher the action. I agree with you, the best choice is lower the fret. But if some one can't or don't want to do that, you must do something with action. Of course it will effect the playing style and it's not a good thing that I also Agree with you.But in some cases changing the action definitely remove the buzzing sound.

Comment: Don't forget the truss rod!  You can adjust neck curvature using the truss rod.

Comment: @theGleep That's a very good idea. If you careful with that I think it's better.

Comment: @aliafsah - I would say it's particularly useful if you're getting a lot of buzz from "middle" frets, but not so much from "outer" frets.  I suppose it *is* an advanced technique...and you'd probably need to re-intonate when you're all done.